# Paperclip PDF Upload Failing (with "is not recognized by the 'identify' command" on rails 3 production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip, passenger, production

I'm getting an error when I try to upload a PDF to production server using paperclip:

*pdf is not recognized by the 'identify' command*

My model looks like this:

```
has_attached_file :document, :styles => { :sm => {:geometry => "160x160>", :format => :png} }
```

ImageMagick is installed, and configured with the proper path to **identify** in production.rb. Photos are uploaded to the same server during testing, and they are processed without error.

I have found another post on StackOverflow here ( [Weird paperclip error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545097/weird-paperclip-error-message) ) which both basically say the same thing- Remove :styles from the model, because imagemagick/identify can't create thumbnails from pdfs.

But it works on my local machine. The pdf is uploaded and the png thumbnail is generated without error. I'm on a mac running passenger/apache/mysql (basically mirroring production as closely as possible).

Any ideas why I'm getting the error on production, and how to fix?

Thanks!
--Mark

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like you haven't got Ghostscript installed.

ImageMagick relies on Ghostscript to handle PDFs. You can check that the problem is with ImageMagick/Ghostscript by running the following command on the server, given a sample.pdf file:

```
$ identify sample.pdf
```

If this returns an error then install Ghostscript and give it another go.